# Mock static method in JUnit 5 using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, mockstatic

I am trying to mock static classes(org.apache.commons.beanutils.Beanutils) for Junit 5 test cases. I came across `mockito-inline` dependency helps with mocking static classes.
I tried to use the `mockito-inline` in the project for some strange reason it give me compilation error in the absence of `mockito-core` library.

With `mockito-core` am getting below:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
The used MockMaker PowerMockMaker does not support the creation of static mocks

Mockito's inline mock maker supports static mocks based on the Instrumentation API.
You can simply enable this mock mode, by placing the 'mockito-inline' artifact where you are currently using 'mockito-core'.
Note that Mockito's inline mock maker is not supported on Android.
    at com.xx.xx.xx.AvroCopyPropertiesInvocationTargetExceptionScenario(CreditOfferServiceTest.java:1197)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Without the core - compilation issue. Please find the test dependency breakdown without `mockito-core`:

```
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-inline:jar:3.6.28:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.10:test
[INFO] |     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.10:test
[INFO] |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.6.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2
```

Comment: Check this link and see if it helps you: https://frontbackend.com/java/how-to-mock-static-methods-with-mockito

Comment: Hi Vitor, It uses junit 4, I need something with junit 5.

Comment: My opinion here ... first of all, get rid of the powermock dependency. Then use mockito-inline and JUnit 5 (junit-jupiter) and you will make things work well.

Comment: Can you edit your questions by adding your `pom.xml` and the test class? I'll help you with it.

Comment: Hi Vitor, Thanks for your time, till mockito-core comes with the ability to mock static and final classes we have decided to run them with Junit 4 itself. I see they are experimenting mockito-inline with the features, once they are satisficed they should be releasing one with mockito-core. That should solve our problem.

Answer (score 23):

You need to use `mockito-inline` version `3.4.0` or higher and remove `mockito-core` from your dependencies (`mockito-inline` depends on `mockito-core` so it will be retrieved automatically).

That way, you will be using mockito static mocking correctly, but it wouldn't solve the exception that you posted.

To fix it, you need to remove all dependencies of `powermock` as it conflicts with `mockito` and causes this error

```
The used MockMaker PowerMockMaker does not support the creation of static mocks
```

Answer (score 14):

In my case we were using spring boot and below dependency for spring-boot-starter-test and mockito-core was coming internally with spring-boot-starter-test

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

use gradle dependencies to find this

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test -> 2.6.6
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.6.6 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.6.6
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.6.6 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.6.6
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.6.6 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.6.6 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.6.6 (*)
|    +--- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.6.0
|    |    +--- net.minidev:json-smart:2.4.7 -> 2.4.8
|    |    |    \--- net.minidev:accessors-smart:2.4.8
|    |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1 -> 9.3
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 -> 1.7.36
|    +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3
|    |    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.2
|    +--- org.assertj:assertj-core:3.21.0
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2
|    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2
|    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.8.2
|    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2 (c)
|    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2 (c)
|    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.8.2 (c)
|    |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.8.2 (c)
|    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2
|    |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.8.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
|    |    |    +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.8.2
|    |    |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.8.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.2
|    |    |    \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.2
|    |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.8.2
|    |         +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.8.2 (*)
|    |         +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2 (*)
|    |         \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.2
|    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:4.0.0
|    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.11.19 -> 1.11.22
|    |    \--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.11.19 -> 1.11.22
|    +--- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.0.0
|    |    \--- org.mockito:mockito-core:4.0.0 (*)
```

So, 2 steps to solve this issue.

Exclude the mockito-core from spring-boot-starter-test

```
testImplementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
 {
   exclude group: 'org.mockito', module :'mockito-core'
 }
```

And now include the mockito-inline

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.6.1'
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: The following article shares an alternative that helped me: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods#configuring-mockito-for-static-methods. This allowed me to configure the existing mockito extension to allow inline mocks

Comment: In what file did you exclude the mockito core?

Comment: @meh93
In build.gradle where we define dependencies.

Answer (score 12):

Add the following per https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to add ***/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker*** file to the class path containing the value ***mock-maker-inline***.
Easiest way to do that is put it in the src/test/resources directory.

For more details check the Mockito documentation.

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final

Comment: works only on java11, tried on java8 , not working

Comment: Worked well with Java 17 application and on Mockito tests running for scenarios dealing with RestClientBuilder.

Answer (score 7):

I have some resolutions steps for same.

Please replace you dependency with below .

```html
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```

if use 4.5.1 or latest your code will work

Also use your try with resource to mock static method

```
try (MockedStatic<WelcomeUtil> theMock = Mockito.mockStatic(WelcomeUtil.class)) {
            theMock.when(() -> WelcomeUtil.generateWelcome("John"))
                   .thenReturn("Guten Tag John");

            assertEquals("Guten Tag John", WelcomeUtil.generateWelcome("John"));
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue while trying to use Mockito5 with **JDK8**, the thing is that "**Instrumentation API**" is not supported by **JDK8**(this is what allows you to mock static classes on runtime) , which is included in **JDK9** and later.

**Instrumentation API** allows you to alter existing byte-code that is loaded in a JVM.

Solution 1 :
Here is the work around I did to overcome this issue :

```
dependencies{
....
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '4.8.0'

    implementation group: 'net.bytebuddy', name: 'byte-buddy-agent', version: '1.12.14'
}

configurations {
    byteBuddyAgent
    compile.extendsFrom byteBuddyAgent
}

test {

    // Add the Byte Buddy agent to the JVM arguments during testing, which will be retrieved by the inline-mockito during runtime.
    doFirst {
        // Get the list of dependencies.
        List<File> dependencies = configurations.compileClasspath.files.toList()

        // Find the jar file for the `byte-buddy-agent` dependency.
        File byteBuddyAgent = dependencies.find { file -> file.path.contains('byte-buddy-agent') }

        if (byteBuddyAgent != null) {
            // Get the path to the jar file.
             jarPath = byteBuddyAgent.absolutePath
             jvmArgs '-javaagent:' + jarPath
        } else {
            // Handle the case when the desired JAR file is not found.
            println "The 'byte-buddy-agent' jar file was not found in the dependencies."
        }
    }

    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}
```

Solution 2 :
Using **PowerMockito** wans't practicle for me beacause I need to run **jacococ** reports to see the code coverage and jacoco doesn't like **PowerMockito** for some reason.